# How to authenticate with AWS Code Artifact Repository from GitHub Actions?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, nuget, github-actions, aws-codeartifact

I have a repository configured in AWS CodeArtifact. I can access it as an administrator from my local machine with `dotnet restore`. Now I am trying to get it to work with GitHub actions for deployment.

I have the following workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-app:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Configure AWS CLI
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: eu-west-2
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.0
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3.2.0
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Login to AWS CodeArtifact
      run: |
          aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --repository ${{ secrets.AWS_CODEARTIFACT_REPOSITORY }} --domain ${{ secrets.AWS_CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN }}
```

However, I get the error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/username is not authorized to perform: codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-west-2:***:domain/*** because no identity-based policy allows the codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken action
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

Key things to know. Code Artifact is in Account A, and the User is in Account B.

### IAM

Policy on the User

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Code Artifact Domain

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-b-id:root"
            },
            "Action": "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-west-2:289579680938:domain/afterlife"
        }
    ]
}
```

CodeArtifact Repository

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-b-id:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
                "codeartifact:ListPackages",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionDependencies",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
                "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "codeartifact:DescribeRepository",
                "codeartifact:DescribePackageVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-west-2:289579680938:repository/afterlife/nuget-mirror"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out.

The key change was that I needed to add the following policy to the IAM user that was active when calling `aws codeartifact login`.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:Describe*",
                "codeartifact:Get*",
                "codeartifact:List*",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I also needed to add the `--owner <account-id-of-where-code-artifact-is-deployed>` to the `aws codeartifact login` command.